# set validatorcontrol.setfocusonerror="true" for all validator controls in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

We are about to release beta version of our website. Lately we have seen that developers have not set setfocusonerror on any of the validaor controls used.We have to set this property.

Now, one solution is to open every page and put this property in place. I am looking for some othe way like some configuration in web.config or some other quick solution.

I have usercontrols and pages. Page derive from base page.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops through all the page controls in the Page_Load event on your base page and do it.  In this example, pass the Page to SetValidationControls

```
protected void SetValidationControls(Control control)
{
   foreach(Control ctrl in control.Controls)
   {
       if(ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator)
       {  
             RequiredFieldValidator req = (RequiredFieldValidator)ctrl;
             req.SetFocusOnError = true;

       }
       else if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator)
       {
             RegularExpressionValidator reg = (RegularExpressionValidator)ctrl;
             reg.SetFocusOnError = true;

       }
       else if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
            SetValidationControls(ctrl);
   }
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of validators that derive from the one's supplied by ASP.NET and use those. This allows you to have more control over it and make application wide changes, for instance, by using the themes & skins file.

For instance, when using the `RequiredFieldValidator`, you can override it and add a new themable property, like this:

```
public class CustomRequiredFieldValidator : RequiredFieldValidator
{
    [ToolboxItem(true), Themeable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    public bool FocusOnError
    {
        get { return this.SetFocusOnError; }
        set { this.SetFocusOnError = value; }
    }
}
```

And in the skin file you can define a default instance of your `CustomRequiredFieldValidator`.

```
<myOwn:CustomRequiredFieldValidator runat="server" FocusOnError="True" />
```

Now all `CustomRequiredFieldValidator` instances in your web application will have their `SetFocusOnError` attribute set.